# How to handle de-normalized data to pass to a flatlist?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-native-flatlist, reselect, normalizr

I was using reselect for select the de-normalized (mapped) data to pass to a flatlist. The main problem is that items are "starable".
The star value is inside the normalized data, so everything will be recalculated on pressing the star, making the app slow slow.

So my question is, how can I handle de-normalizing data when your normalized data change frequently?

Solution that i've found:

**1) Move away the interactive data?**

But now I have to split data on startup, and on every data fetch. This is slow, but if you are using a "loader" (activityIndicator/ refreshing indicator) that would not be a true problem.
So now I can denormalize on reselect, and the cache will expire only on data fetch: that's good.

**2) Using selector only on the array of Ids, without touching normalized data?**

No need to map, if I can let flatlist handle that.
But this will need to pass both array and normalized data to the flatlist, using the array for the data and the normalized as extradata.
But now, I'm not sure, there are a ton of data passed to every flatlist item.

**3) Don't use relect, but maybe paginate the data?**

Now I have to map only few elements, that increment with onEndReach.
the returned array when pressing the star will be small, so usually fast.

Where I think to still need reselect? sorting data
On a normalized data source, sorting isn't light. (first map, than sort).
But hard without using reselect for the denormalization.

**Any idea for what path to follow? Better solutions?**

ps. sorry for my bad english, thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) I've found that using `React.Component` and passing the normalized filtered prop, this may work well.
so something like:

```
  _renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <ListItem
      data={this.props.data[item.id]}
      onPressFavorite={this.props.onPressFavorite}
    />
  );
```

Is this a valid pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if u figured out but maybe a solution is not use FlatList and iterate like this:

```
const normalizeData = []
Object.keys(normalizeData).map((key, id) => {
          const data = normalizeData[key];
return <WrapperComponent key={key} item={data} />
}
```

You can add and ScrollView too, that let you recreate FlatList behaviour.